# Seperate Function Decleration and Implementation in F#

Tags: function, f#, implementation, declaration

I have two functions that call each other. In F#, in order for function A to call function B, B must be declared before the declaration of function A. 
So when having two functions that call each other - what do I do?

I thought of declaring both function definitions at the beginning of the module, and implemeting them later on, but couldn't find any information on how to do so in F#. 
In C# it would look like this:

```
 public void A();
 public void B();
    .
    .
    .
 public void A()
     {B();}
 public void B()
    {A();}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: Mutual recursion? Google it. Hint: `let rec ... and ...`

Comment: Well, appearantly the only problem I had is knowing what to Google... Thank you all!